Find the diagonalizing matrix for a general 2*2 real valued symmetric matrix
I have the following 2*2 real symmetric matrix. $mp$ and $mm$ are the eigenvalues. How do we find $\cos{\phi}$ and $\sin{\phi}$ in terms of the $n$, $y$, $mp$, $mm$?
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\phi ) & -\sin (\phi ) \\
 \sin (\phi ) & \cos (\phi ) \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & n \\
 n & n^2+y \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\phi ) & \sin (\phi ) \\
 -\sin (\phi ) & \cos (\phi ) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{mp} & 0 \\
 0 & \text{mm} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$


Provide your matrix equation as MMA code in addition to the $\TeX$. 2) What have you tried so far?



Strangely, MMA does not work for it. This may be, due to the matrix form. 2) I tried every possible way but gave rise to complicated solutions.


Well, the solutions can be complicated. You find them with Eigensystem. For $y=0$ they have a simple form $\phi=\arctan(-n)$

Since the size of this matrix is 2x2, some elementary facts from linear algebra will help you a lot. I assume the matrix is real. Since it is symmetric, its eigenvalues, mm and mp, are real. Let me assume mm < mp. Then  is clearly the arctan of v, where v is the eigenvector with eigenvalue mm. So
mat = {{1, n}, {n, n^2 + y}}; mat//MatrixForm


Eigenvalues[mat]


By the assumption above, mm is the first eigenvalue. So the corresponding eigenvector is given by
eigenvector = Eigenvectors[mat][[1]]


Therefore,
phi = ArcTan @@ eigenvector


This is the final answer. You can specify n, y to whatever values you like:
phi /. {n -> 2, y -> -3}


Remark: if  is a valid answer, so is   + Pi.

Why is ArcTan \phi ? And what does '1' go in ArcTan[....., 1]?

ArcTan[x,y] is a refined version of ArcTan[y/x]. Please consult the Wolfram Document about this. You want an "normalized" eigenvector of the form (cos , sin ). But Mathematica's EigenVector usually returns "un-normalized" eigenvector  (vx, vy). They belongs to the same eigenvalue if and only if vx = c  cos  and vy = c sin  for some nonzero c. This is equivalent to tan  = vy/vx, that is,   = ArcTan (vy/vx).

Thanks! you wrote "They belong to the same eigenvalue if and only if vx = c cos  and vy = c sin  for some nonzero c"... So, in the above example c = 1, right? 2nd: your assumption that "Let me assume mm < mp" practically has no effect, right? Of course mm< mp, but the result can also be found for the eigenvector corresponding to the 'mp' eigenvalue. Do you agree?

Oh, so  = ArcTan (vy/vx) mainly takes into account the normalization of the eigenvector since Mathematica's output of the 'EigenVector' is not 'normalized'. Certainly, your answer works well, but I need to understand the details. Thanks!

One smaller question: The mathematica output for the "Eigenvector" is supposed to be a column or row form. Documentation does not say anything about this. I am cross-verifying your answer by normalizing the eigenvectors manual;y, how it does not agree. I doubt I may be taking the output for each eigenvalue as a row vector. Could you please comment on this too?

Eigenvector returns a "list" of eigenvectors. In MMA, each (eigen) vector is simply given as a list.  So, if  {c1,c2} = Eigenvalues[mat] and {v1,v2} = Eigenvectors[mat], then, A.v1==c1v1 and A.v2==c2v2. That's all. Both v1 and v2 are just lists. You can regard them either as row vector or column vector.

mm < mp assumption is used  to guarantee (cos , sin ) is the eigenvector with eigenvalue mm. For more details, please consult "matrix diagonalization" in any standard linear algebra textbook. This is Math, not Mathematica. I'll stop there.

Thanks. I have accepted your answer. However, I don't agree with your last comment, 'This is Math, not Mathematica'. My questions are bout Mathematica. I asked every about the Mathematica treatment!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Can this method be applied for 3*3 real symmetrix matrix?

Why does the Cos[phi] of the final result correspond to the Sin[phi] entry in the orthogonal matrix?

You do know that the above will generate 4 equations but you are solving for two variables?  Let $\sin(\theta)=s,\cos(\theta)=c$ then we get 4 equations to solve for 2 variables $s,c$.  Which is overdetermined. If you pick two equations then you can solve it. Depending on which 2 equations you pick you get different solutions.
(lhs={{c,-s},{s,c}}.{{1,n},{n,n^2+y}}.{{c,s},{-s,c}})//MatrixForm


(rhs = {{mp, 0}, {0, mm}}) // MatrixForm


(eqs = FullSimplify[Thread[Flatten /@ (lhs == rhs)]]) // Column


Lets solve first and last equation for $c,s$ since those has $mp,n,y,c,s$ in them.
 Solve[{eqs[[1]], eqs[[4]]}, {c, s}, Reals, 
         Assumptions -> {n > 0, mm > 0, mp > 0, y > 0}]



Thanks but how to find a unique solution? The output has infinite conditions! Note that all the constants, n, mm, mp, x, y are real non-zero and positive numbers in my case.

Assumptions -> {n > 0, mm > 0, mp > 0, y > 0} is not a valid option for solve.

@SciJewel  why do you say Assumptions is not valid option for Solve? There was no error. And help https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve  shows an example under Option using Assumptions.   Solve[x^2 == a, x, Reals, Assumptions -> a > 0] ?

sorry version issue
